# Beginner Haskell, quickcheck generator

Tags: haskell

I want to generate an increasing number of lists i.e.

```
 prelude>sample' incList
 [[],[19],[6,110],[24,67,81]....]
```

How should I use vectorOf?

```
 incList:: Gen [Integer]
 incList=   
 do x<-vectorOf [0..] arbitrary
    return x
```

I cant think of a way to just take out the first number from the list one at a time :/ Maybe something with fmap take 1, I dunno..

Comment: But here the type of objects is not `[Integer]`, but `[[Integer]]`.

Comment: May be a function like `sequence $ [0..] >>= pure . (flip vectorOf) arbitrary` with type signature `Gen [[Integer]]` does what you need. The sub arrays are increasing though but in length not as ascending.

Answer (score 1):

I think you here aim to do too much at once. Let us first construct a generator for a random list of `Ord`ered objects with a given length in ascending order:

```
import Data.List(sort)

incList :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Int -> Gen [a]
incList n = fmap sort (vectorOf n arbitrary)
```

Now we can construct a `Gen`erator that generates an endless list of lists by each time incrementing the size with one:

```
incLists :: (Arbitrary a, Ord a) => Gen [[a]]
incLists = mapM incList [0..]
```

We can then generate values from this `Gen`erator with [**`generate :: Gen a -> IO [a]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.12.6.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:generate):

```
Prelude File> generate incLists :: IO [[Int]]
[[],[-19],[6,25],[-19,-14,15],[-4,6,20,28],[-23,-19,-6,-1,22],[-29,-21,-13,-9,-9,15],[-23,-15,-4,3,3,27,27],[-29,-29,-26,-25,18,19,23,27],[-24,-23,-16,-14,0,13,17,17,23],[-29,-15,-12,-4,-1,1,2,20,22,26],[-26,-24,-22,-16,-12,5,5,10,11,25,29],[-29,-28,-20,-14,-9,-7,-3,14,15,20,26,28],...]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, excuse me if I'm wrong but dont you change the type of  incList this way? I need it according to the assignmment to be exactly of the type incList:: Gen [Integer], also that one should use do-notation but that wasnt mandatory.

Comment: @ErikHNguyen: well a `sample'` generate an list of items (11 iirc), so that means you have no control over constraints (like incrementing the size of the list) each step.

Comment: "give def for a generator for lists of Integers, where for every list generated, the length of the list increments by one".Maybe I phrased it wrong in my question? sorry eng is not my mother tongue.

Comment: @ErikHNguyen: no, that was correct. But a `sample'` can definitely not do that, since `sample'` always generates a list of 11 elements. So it would, regardless of the argument, stop after generating 11 elements.

Comment: so it would be a list of eleven elements which each have elements ranging from 0 to 10? I think that is how they want it to be

Comment: @ErikHNguyen: but the idea of `sample'` is typically that a programmer itself is *not* supposed to add such constraints to the *sequence* of elements. Typically the idea of `Arbitrary` is to make a sample with some sort of distribution, but not with *transitive dependencies*.